# "Достаточно много" - тавтология? "Довольно мало" - абсурд?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если так, то какое правило остановит поток этих "включений" в речь?

Answer (score 2):

Это нормальные способы относительной количественной оценки в ситуации, когда не делается прямого сопоставления с чем-либо.

"Достаточно много" означает, что в общем контексте рассматриваемой темы с имеющимся количеством чего-то следует считаться. Простое же "достаточно" требует прямого указания, "для чего" именно чего-то достаточно.

"Довольно мало" - указание на то, что количество чего-то в данном контексте несущественно (без конкретного сопоставления с чем-либо). Слово "довольно" употребляется не в значении "достаточности", а указывает на относительность оценки "мало" - в отличие от того, что имеет место в выражении "достаточно мало" - оно действительно неудачно, поскольку внутренне противоречиво: "достаточность" - всегда атрибут отн. большого количества.

Comment: достаточно - это уже в значении хватит. Мало - недобор, много - перебор.
доволен-недоволен, тут и так все ясно.  
Бессмыслица получается, если подставить синонимы.
А как вариант- попытка запутать на простейшем, внеся элемент неопределенности.
Выгодно только тому, кто втюхивает таким выражением собственное неумение или нежелание привести точные цифры, полный отказ от сравнительной характеристики.

Comment: "достаточно" - это "удовлетворяет максимальным требованиям".

"довольно" - "удовлетворяет минимальным требованиям".

А если Вы ни разу не сталкивались с изменением значения слова в ходе использования - на форуме Вам помочь не смогут.

Comment: Alex_ander: "способы относительной количественной оценки"... 

Думаю, не в количестве (точном числе, как у petro) оценка, а в качестве: не в до-ста-точном, а в до-стать-нем - достать, достичь, состояться, завершиться. Отсюда и минимизированное - без ещё одного наречия: Достаточно (и Довольно) слов, доказательств, ссылок, жертв.

Answer (score 1):

> какое правило остановит?..

Никакое. Эти сочетания давно уже вросли в русский язык. Используются и словаристами.

См. 
**Русский орфографический словарь** Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.
© Электронная версия, «ГРАМОТА.РУ», 2001–2007. 
(http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/lop/ ):

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Словаристы" - труженики от статистики, фиксируют и не создают ни прецедентов, что "вросли в язык", ни правил. Хладнокровные или теплохладные.

Comment: Слава, скажите, пожалуйста, как вы сделали эту картинку из словаря? Я уже писал, но кто-то мой комментарий удалил.

Comment: Серж, боюсь, что не смогу Вам помочь. Дело в том, что у меня операционная система МАС.  Скриншот делаю с помощью кнопок "cmd + shift + 4". У Вас же, скорее всего, Windows. Как делается скриншот в этой ОС, я не знаю.

Comment: А-а, спасибо. Ясно. Значит вы сделали скриншот. Скриншот я могу делать. Я думал, вы делаете при помощи функций данного форума.

Answer (score 0):

Где здесь "абсурд"?
"Достаточно" и "довольно" - "уточняющие" характеристики, которые могут дополнять любую характеристику объекта или явления, не подразумевающую точного вычисления ("достаточно (довольно) хорошо", "достаточно (довольно) плохо", "достаточно (довольно) точно", "достаточно (довольно) приблизительно" и т.д.).

Comment: "Достаточно приблизительно". Это может дополнить характеристику объекта? 

Шутка с большой долей шутки. Виталина_ZX поздравить как её автора или greydog?

Comment: ..Ну почему же "шутка"..

Допустим: "..значения, полученные подобным способом достаточно приблизительны. И использовать их для количественной оценки не стоит.."

Comment: Или, например, вот: http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B&clid=1923020

Comment: достаточно в данном случае слово-"паразит", кому и что достаточно, неизвестно.
сказать просто: "приблизительны" никак, сказать: "по моему мнению, приблизительны"- тоже никак. Зато внести нейтральное по смыслу "достаточно" ой как проясняет ситуацию.

Это просто глупый штамп, типа "экономика должна быть экономной", "углубить процесс", таких безграмотных штампов в литературной и разговорной речи навалом.

Comment: И опять Вы торопитесь с ярлыками. Термин "приблизительно" имеет весьма широкий "спектр применения". "±1,5%" - это "приблизительно", "плюс-минус два лаптя по карте" - тоже "приблизительно".

При таком "разбросе" сказать "приблизительно" - то же самое, что не сказать ничего. По этому - необходимы уточнения ("несколько", "довольно", "достаточно", "слишком" и т.п.). И, как бы Вы ни пытались доказать обратное, от выбора "уточнения" зависит смысл фразы.

Comment: Вы сами написали цифры и меру приблизительности, то есть обозначили числом погрешность измерения.  Это уже достаточно для оценки. А спектр применения-это те же яйца с неопределенностью, вид снизу. Штамп замусоленный.Несколько--это сколько? в пределах десятка или трех, или четырех десятков? несколько-это на усмотрение дающего или берущего, но явно больше одного и как правило не больше десятка. Потому что счет у нас в десятичной системе, дальше надо несколько десятков, либо несколько пар, несколько дюжин.
Несколько--это вполне определенный диапазон чисел--погрешность не очень важна при этом.

Comment: А вот несколько глупо, не с чем сравнивать степень глупизны. Ее меры еще не придумали. А несколько умный вообще бессмыслица, а довольно умный дядя, это значит я им доволен.Довольно глупый дядя, просто казуистическое названия дурака. а слишком глупый дядя, совсем дурак. 

Слишком это перебор. мало недобор, слишком мало--опять бессмыслица и штамп. перебор недобора.
У всех штампы, типа слишком много говорить стал, сами не замечаем, насколько привыкли к таким оборотам. Тут еще понятно, откуда пошло, из "слыш-ка, много говорить стал".

Comment: Такое ощущение, что русский для Вас - не родной.

"Несколько" применяется не только в качестве "количественного", но и в качестве, пардон за "корявость", "качественного" определения. Напр., "несколько наивный" - не означает "наивный несколько раз". Это, скорее, "наивен, но не настолько, чтоб это раздражало". То-же и с "несколько глупо".

"Слишком" - характеристика "относительная". "Мало" - "качественная". "Слишком мало (для)" - вполне "законная" конструкция. Можно заменить на "недостаточно", но получится слишком "казённо". Не всем нравится.

Comment: Эта относительно и качественно, не русское, а местечково-ашкеназское, от эйнштейнов всяких:

могу вам спеть и маленький куплет.
 Про две большие разницы,
 про то, как всем достаточно и мало на буфет.



Когда приезжаешь в Одессу, именно такая "русская" речь на каждом углу.

Comment: Для снятия напряжённости, - с этого же форума: Длинная, достаточно, трасса. Достаточно тёмное время года. Достаточно молодые мужчины. Достаточно стрессовая работа - оператор банка. Довольно поздно вызвали пожарных. Двигатель достаточно прожорливый. Ребёночек достаточно рано умер. Достаточно вялый в воздухе самолёт. Пижма от Екатеринбурга находится достаточно близко.